# How to choose the right predictors and evaluate if a binomial glm model is good?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, model

So, basically I have data with millions of observations on trees. The data was sampled in different time periods, so it is structured in a way that one line contains information on one tree on the first and second measurement. Each tree is recorded dead or alive on the second measurement. That is basically what I am trying to model, the mortality probability of a tree. Besides tree data I also have hundreds of potential predictors of soil and weather data from the points where the data was collected.

For now I have been using a binomial glm model with a cloglog link. I am struggling to find the best way of how to actually choose the right predictors, and evaluate if a model is good. I started choosing predictors hierarchically based on my knowledge and then taking out the ones with a low `p` value, evaluate the models between them based on the `AIC` and the overall fit based on a pseudo `R2` and the `AUC`. The more I read and investigate the more I think that all those are wrong scores to use. I want to have as little predictors as possible, ideally 5-10 but I am lost and confused on how to do so. Now I am thinking to use `LASSO` but I played around a bit with it, and it seems it does not take out any predictors, maybe because the dataset is so large and there is some predictive power in all of the variables.

Can anybody give me some tips on how to best approach this?

Comment: As far as I know, all variants of pseudo $R^2$ for logistic regression suffer from a number of problems. It might be more interesting to have a look at the confusion matrix or the AUC (aka "c statistic") for model assessment. What does it look like?

Comment: Concerning variable selection, you can have a look at LASSO, aka "elastic net" for GLMs (R package glmnet). Particularly devised as a means to avoid overfitting by introducing a regularization term, it has the side effect of "shrinking" the coefficients of irrelevant predictors to zero, which is a form of variable selection. Beware however, that the selection is arbitrary in case of (multi-) collinear variables.

Comment: @cdalitz The AUC is between 0.7 and 0.8, depending on the variables I include.

Comment: If the goal is prediction, it's better to use all available predictors. Skip the feature selection step based on p-values.

Comment: @dipetkov I am thinking now to use all the available predictors I have, which is a lot, and then use LASSO, to try and fit the model, what do you think?

Comment: @dipetkov In many situations, omitting variables improves the AUC. I would conclude that even for prediction, omitting "noise" variables can improve performance.

Comment: @cdalitz If I understood correctly (by just reading about it this morning) LASSO is like a machine learning process, where it will basically take all the predictors that I have and then find the best possible combinations from them? Am I wrong?

Comment: @cdalitz The OP provides few details (and just because there is lots of data, it doesn't mean the data has a lot of signal and we could expect great performance). However, I'd guess that the OP may have more success by experimenting with other algorithms (random forest for example) rather than to do feature selection for a GLM.

Comment: @dipetkov Basically I am trying to predict whether a tree is going to die or not, I have data on forest structure, which is about 5-10 variables, and then hundreds of various abiotic (soil) and weather data.

Comment: It's always good to provide more information. Now that you've explained the problem setting a bit,  my next question would be -- how are these trees sampled (as there can be dependencies between trees that grow nearby). I suggest that you write a new question that describes your data and problem in detail, explains the approach you've tried so far and then asks for advice.

Comment: @dipetkov I have reposted the question. I will close this one.

Comment: Please don't start multiple threads for the same question.  Just edit this one.  So that readers can have ready access to the comment thread, I have merged your questions.